# Weather app with Vue js and Open Weather Map API and 7 day weather forecast

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Hi guys I'm trying to build a weather app with a 7 day forecast of a city to be informed by the user. It has to be in Vue js and use the `Open Weather Map API`.

I managed to make the app and connect it to the `Open Weather Map API` displaying the weather. But I couldn't display the 7-day forecast. I read the API documentation and didn't find examples to help me.

can you help me?

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app" :class="typeof weather.main != 'undefined' && weather.main.temp > 16 ? 'warm' : ''">
    <main>
      <div class="search-box">
        <input 
          type="text" 
          class="search-bar" 
          placeholder="Digite uma cidade..."
          v-model="query"
          @keypress="fetchWeather"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="weather-wrap" v-if="typeof weather.main != 'undefined'">
        <div class="location-box">
          <div class="location">{{ weather.name }}, {{ weather.sys.country }}</div>
          <div class="date">{{ dateBuilder() }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="weather-box">
          <div class="temp">{{ Math.round(weather.main.temp) }}°c</div>
          <div class="weather">{{ weather.weather[0].main }}</div>
          <div class="weather">{{ weather.weather[0].main }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      api_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      url_base: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/',
      query: '',
      weather: {}
      
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchWeather (e) {
      if (e.key == "Enter") {
        fetch(`${this.url_base}weather?q=${this.query}&units=metric&APPID=${this.api_key}`)
          .then(res => {
            return res.json();
          }).then(this.setResults);
      }
    },
    setResults (results) {
      this.weather = results;
      this.weather.icon = results;
    },
  
    dateBuilder () {
      let d = new Date();
      let months = ["Janeiro", "fevereiro", "março", "abril", "maio", "junho", "julho", "agosto", "setembro", "outubro", "novembro", "dezembro"];
      let days = ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"];
      let day = days[d.getDay()];
      let date = d.getDate();
      let month = months[d.getMonth()];
      let year = d.getFullYear();
      return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`;
    }
  }
}

</script>

<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#app {
  background-image: url('./assets/cold-bg.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
#app.warm {
  background-image: url('./assets/warm-bg.jpg');
}
main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 25px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75));
}
.search-box {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.search-box .search-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  
  color: #313131;
  font-size: 20px;
  appearance: none;
  border:none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 0px 16px 0px 16px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.search-box .search-bar:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  border-radius: 16px 0px 16px 0px;
}
.location-box .location {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.location-box .date {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}
.weather-box {
  text-align: center;
}
.weather-box .temp {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 102px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-shadow: 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 30px 0px;
  box-shadow: 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.weather-box .weather {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
  text-shadow: 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
</style>
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API call for only 7 days forecast should be:

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&lang={en}&units=metric&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts&appid={apiKey}
```

in object from response You will get `timezone_offset":`  so you can loop over array `daily` to get date:

```
const myDate = new Date(obj.dt*1000-(obj.timezone_offset*1000)));
```

Comment: Thanks but Would you have an example for you to see?